# Confusion over my API key

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-key, rate-limit

*This is directed at the team, since nobody else will be able to help.*

The key I took out for StackMobile is behaving strangely. I make a few requests, and then the limit resets to 0. (By limit, I'm referring to the X-RateLimit-whatever-its-called header.)

**Update:** it's not the limit (10000) that's getting reset, it's the number of requests remaining. It starts at 9999 and every few requests, it resets to 9999.

Comment: You can view the results of the headers from the last request at http://stackmobile.com/about.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

Remember, that the API limit is per-IP and per-site.  For you, the important part is **per-site**.

So, SO gets 10,000 requests a day, SF gets 10,000 requests a day, etc. etc.  This can make your about kind of... confusing, as its showing the *last* requests headers.